# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined on my function

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I am writing a function to save a user's supplied data when internet connection fails

I have two functions, the first i named insert_into_Outbox that saves to my indexedDB temporary and register a sync event in my serviceworker while internet connection is down. The sync event would run and save the data on the database when network comes back immediately, the the other on click function runs the "save a data" process.

When i call the insert_into_Outbox function in my "save a data" onclick function , i am getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" error response....How do i get it to respond with a promise ??

```
//Code to run the entire process of saving to indexedDB and create sync event
$(document).on('click','#save', function(_event){
        var item_name = []; var item_code = []; var item_desc = []; var item_price = [];

         $('.item_name').each(function(){ item_name.push( $(this).text()); });
         $('.item_code').each(function(){ item_code.push( $(this).text()); });
         $('.item_desc').each(function(){ item_desc.push( $(this).text()); });
         $('.item_price').each(function(){ item_price.push( $(this).text()); });
        var data = {method:'post',body:JSON.stringify({'cmd':'insert','item_name':item_name,'item_code':item_code, 'item_desc':item_desc, 'item_price':item_price})};
    _event.waitUntil(
         insert_into_Outbox('MyTestDatabase',data).then(() => {return navigator.serviceWorker.ready;})
           .then(reg => reg.sync.register('save-items'))
           .then(() => display_on_screen(obj = {'item_name':item_name,'item_code':item_code, 'item_desc':item_desc, 'item_price':item_price}))
            )
            .catch(() => insert_into_database(data)); 
});

//insert_into_outbox function
insert_into_Outbox = function(store_name,data){try{       
         //Adding to the Database
        var store = getObjectStore(store_name,'readwrite'); var req;
            try {
                req = store.add(data);
            }catch (e){console.log('error inserting into store: '+e.message);}
                req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
                    console.log("Insertion in DB successful");
                };
                req.onerror = function() {
                    console.log("Insertion in DB Failed ", this.error);
                };    
      }catch(e){console.log('error inserting into indexDB store: '+e.message)}
  }
```

Comment: `insert_into_Outbox` doesn't return a promise so it wouldn't have a `.then()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `insert_into_Outbox` as a promise you should return a promise. Try something like this:

```js
insert_into_Outbox = function(store_name,data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {       
             //Adding to the Database
            var store = getObjectStore(store_name,'readwrite');
            var req;
                try {
                    req = store.add(data);

                } catch (e) {
                    console.log('error inserting into store: '+e.message);
                    reject(e);
                }
                    req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
                        console.log("Insertion in DB successful");
                        resolve(evt);
                    };
                    req.onerror = function() {
                        console.log("Insertion in DB Failed ", this.error);
                        reject(this.error);
                    };    
        } catch(e) {
             console.log('error inserting into indexDB store: '+e.message);
             reject(e);
        }
    }
});
```